# Boosting the grep search using GNU parallel

Tags: multithreading, grep, pattern-matching, gnu-parallel, ripgrep

I am using the following grep script to output all the unmatched patterns:

```
grep -oFf patterns.txt large_strings.txt | grep -vFf - patterns.txt > unmatched_patterns.txt
```

patterns file contains the following 12-characters long substrings (some instances are shown below):

```
6b6c665d4f44
8b715a5d5f5f
26364d605243
717c8a919aa2
```

large_strings file contains extremely long strings of around 20-100 million characters longs (a small piece of the string is shown below):

```
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
```

How can we speed up the above script (gnu parallel, xargs, fgrep, etc.)? I tried using `--pipepart` and `--block` but it doesn't allow you to pipe two grep commands.

Btw these are all hexadecimal strings and patterns.

The working code below is a little faster than the traditional grep:

```
rg -oFf patterns.txt large_strings.txt | rg -vFf - patterns.txt > unmatched_patterns.txt
```

`grep` took an hour to finish the process of pattern matching while it took `ripgrep` around 45 mins.

Comment: 1) try `LC_ALL=C grep ...` 2) use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Comment: 3) try one or more `grep -oF -e '6b6c665d4f44' -e '8b715a5d5f5f' large_strings.txt` instead of `grep -oFf patterns.txt large_strings.txt`

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep. I am trying ripgrep now. Still waiting for it to finish.

Comment: @Sundeep doing the patterns individually will take a lot of time as my patterns.txt file has over 30 million patterns :(

Comment: well, if you have millions of search terms AND lines with millions of characters, a custom search engine would be needed to speed it up.. there may be some tool already available as well... I would suggest to ask on https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/discussions (the tool author and others may have better suggestions)

Comment: @Sundeep `ripgrep` worked for me. It's much faster and accurate than the traditional grep. Thank you so much. I will add the working code in my original post.

Comment: You might try ripgrep built with Hyperscan instead, it could be much faster: https://sr.ht/~pierrenn/ripgrep/ In general, searching for millions of patterns is a very specialized use case, and neither ripgrep nor GNU grep will handle it particularly well. It wouldn't surprise me if most of the runtime was actually being spent compiling the matcher rather than the actual search. But since you haven't provided a way to reproduce your results, it's impossible to say.

Comment: @BurntSushi indeed I will try this out. I found the following script in conjunction with `--pipepart` and `--pipe` significantly faster: `parallel --pipepart --block -1 -a large_strings.txt rg -oFf patterns.txt | rg -Ff - patterns.txt > unmatched_patterns.txt` *credit to @Ole Tange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to use `grep` try:

```
build_k_mers() {
    k="$1"
    slot="$2"
    perl -ne 'for $n (0..(length $_)-'"$k"') {                                                                                               
       $prefix = substr($_,$n,2);                                                                                                            
       $fh{$prefix} or open $fh{$prefix}, ">>", "tmp/kmer.$prefix.'"$slot"'";                                                                
       $fh = $fh{$prefix};                                                                                                                   
       print $fh substr($_,$n,'"$k"'),"\n"                                                                                                   
    }'
}
export -f build_k_mers

rm -rf tmp
mkdir tmp
export LC_ALL=C
# search strings must be sorted for comm                                                                                                     
parsort patterns.txt | awk '{print >>"tmp/patterns."substr($1,1,2)}' &

# make shorter lines: Insert \n(last 12 char before \n) for every 32k                                                                         
# This makes it easier for --pipepart to find a newline                                                                                      
# It will not change the kmers generated                                                                                                     
perl -pe 's/(.{32000})(.{12})/$1$2\n$2/g' large_strings.txt > large_lines.txt
# Build 12-mers                                                                                                                              
parallel --pipepart --block -1 -a large_lines.txt 'build_k_mers 12 {%}'
# -j10 and 20s may be adjusted depending on hardware
parallel -j10 --delay 20s 'parsort -u tmp/kmer.{}.* > tmp/kmer.{}; rm tmp/kmer.{}.*' ::: `perl -e 'map { printf "%02x ",$_ } 0..255'`
wait
parallel comm -23 {} {=s/patterns./kmer./=} ::: tmp/patterns.??
```

I have tested this on `patterns.txt`: 9GBytes/725937231 lines, `large_strings.txt`: 19GBytes/184 lines and on my 64-core machine it completes in 3 hours.